# Don't give tech to the primitives for real

Tags: technology, history

It's a common cliche for advanced cultures just giving tech to less advanced cultures always resulting in a bad outcome. Are there any real examples of this in human history that could be quoted in a story to take this to the next level? Any time or country will do.

Comment: This is more of a history question than a Worldbuilding one.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I would argue differently, as the no tech sharing rules are usually found in scifi, especially space operas.  Star Trek's Prime Directive is generally the template but even then, the series took it's time to explore the problems with that (what if you interfere with a primative species to save them from an extinction level event).

Comment: @hszmv But the question *specifically asks* about examples in human history.

Comment: Genesis 2:16-17? *"Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die"*. Guess what. Man did eat the fruit of the tree of knowledge, and look what happened.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The Prime Directive was inspired by such events in human history such as Trans-Columbian Trade, which seems to be once sided, until one realizes several technologies were swapped over the Atlantic (predominantly cultivations of certain produce that have become staple crops to human diets the world over, such as corn and potatoes.).  The problem was more that the New World was less prepared for Old World diseases.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that political history is just as much a part of worldbuilding as plate tectonics. Unless you want to just limit this to physical planet creation, and that's kinda dull. Everything asked here has some science or another behind it. That doesn't make the question invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienNonInterferenceClause) has some roots in both [natural photography](https://nanpa.org/2018/12/07/should-photographers-intervene-in-nature/) and also in colonialism. Both of these subjects can get people riled up, but I am not here to do that.

## Alcohol

There are many instances from European colonialism where some technology has brought about ruin. Let's take [introducing distilled spirits to Native Americans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6761887/). Colonists were not the best models for alcohol consumption. They also actively exploited this new technology against native people's, getting them drunk in negotiations simply to get better deals out of them.

## Arms Introductions

You can argue that any modernization of armies through the introduction of firearms was a bad thing. It happened all over the world due to colonialism, from North America to Africa's [Ethiopian military modernization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_the_Ethiopian_Empire) Yes, these weapons have hunting uses, but killing people is generally bad<sup>[citation required]</sup> and arms transfers generally result in *more killing.*

This concern even comes up today. Western nations sending arms and armor to Ukraine can be seen as "more advanced" (by measure of "how well armored are they?") Civilizations transferring technology to a less advanced civilization.

## Opium, Tobacco, and Other Drugs

Ever heard of the [opium wars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_Wars)? Okay, this was the introduction of opium, but not the process to make it, to China. The introduction of this drug (a technology!) started a chain of events that brought China into dire political and personal situations.

## Cargo Cults

During WWII, many pacific islanders we're exposed to the armies fighting a war with (to them) unimaginable machines. Once the war ended, these societies were left with an appetite for "cargo:" they wanted goods from the broader world without knowing how or why these goods were brought to their island. People made [cargo cult](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)s, attempting to bring the cargo back.

These cults were undoubtedly harmful. These people went through grueling efforts and got nothing in return. They could have spent that effort doing more productive things that would actually improve their lives: running their society!

Comment: The introduction of opium by the English into China and the introduction of fiery water  by Europeans into America are very different meanings of the word introduction. The English introduced opium into China in the sense that they carried it over the border illegally; the Chinese had opium, but its sale was illegal or at least strictly controlled. The Indians did not have fiery water, and anyway had no legal or judicial system or a concept of smuggling something. And cargo cults are actually a counterexample; cargo cults are what happens when technology is *not* introduced to the natives.

Comment: @AlexP "introduced," at least in English and in this context, can mean different things. For example, I can introduce someone to fishing by explaining, showing, immersing them around, or teaching fishing. All are valid interpretations of "introduce." Language is vague.

Comment: Yes, the [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) the point of the comment. But then the question itself is guilty of this, as it does not explain what "giving tech to less advanced cultures" is supposed to mean. Educating them? Selling them stuff? Gifting them stuff? (And I still believe that the wholesale smuggling of opium into the Celestial Empire cannot be honestly called the "introduction" of a technology. The English did not introduce any technology. They just smuggled an illegal drug over the border. The drug was known in the country, they brought nothing new.)

Comment: Glad to see this is getting so many responses. I didn't even consider tech being given to intentionally cause harm which is a good point